# 18.04 cached LDAP passwords

Tags: 18.04, laptop, authentication, ldap

Over the last week I have been working on getting the (Ubuntu 18.04) LDAP directory information cached locally to allow the use of roaming users(on Laptops). Getting the LDAP client setup correctly took a little digging around, but I was eventually able to get it to work. There are a few guides available to help out on this matter, although most are outdated. However, when it comes to cached data, I have not been able to find a fully comprehensive guide on the matter. As it seems there are a number of different ways to do this (nscd, sssd) and as it seems these still have a number of bugs, making it even harder to get up and running.

Guides I've found:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l0e8rG0mku8
https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/authentication-caching-with-nscd/

I'm running a simple LDAP server (on a ClearOS 6 dist), and would just like a centralized way of organizing user data for roaming users.

Does anyone have a comprehensive guide(or success) on getting 18.04/LDAP/Cached passwords up and running on laptops???

Comment: Another good article, but still no cigar:
https://cyberspace709.wordpress.com/2016/08/25/how-to-setup-openldap-client-in-ubuntu-14-using-ssd/

Want to know more about PAM, here's something that helped me:
https://www.linux.com/news/understanding-pam

Comment: I have been pulling my hair out for the last week and a half on this same issue. I've tried the `ldap` route with no success and switched to `ldapd` but it comes incorporated with `nscd` and `nslcd` for caching which do not seem to work. I'll try the `sssd` route and get back to you if I'm successful

Comment: I started with the sssd route, got sidetracked and got halfway. Although this seems to be a viable option.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I fell into a trap and had to switch the strategy. I have successfully cached my LDAP passwords by simply installing and configuring `sssd` on a clean installation of 18.04. Nothing else required. I'm sorry I can't share my configuration file at the moment but if you manage to find the solution and post it, I'll upvote you. Otherwise, I'll post my solution as soon as I have the time

Comment: It looks like sssd would really be the way to go. Any chance that you could share your configuration files and experience with it?

Comment: I'm sorry, I cannot share files from my organization. I did solve all my issues with just installing sssd and probably some other accessory library like libpam-sssd or libnss-sssd. I don't remember well anymore which one or some other one that was too obvious that I actually noticed. What I do remember is not having to configure much of anything